# How to write a test class for ApexTestQueueItem?

Tags: apex, unit-test

Ho to write a test method to cover the below ?

```
 public static Set<Id> getCompletedTestJobsIds(Map<Id, List<ApexTestQueueItem>> testJobQItemsMap)
{
    //Initialize the completedTestJobIds with list all given Job Ids.
    Set<Id> completedTestJobIds = new Set<Id>();
    completedTestJobIds.addAll(testJobQItemsMap.keySet());

    //Remove uncompleted job Ids from completedTestJobIds.
    for (Id testJobId : testJobQItemsMap.keySet())
    {
        //Iterate through all TestQueueItems for the current testjobId.
        for (ApexTestQueueItem testQItem : testJobQItemsMap.get(testJobId))
        {
            if (testQItem.Status != 'Completed' && testQItem.Status != 'Failed' && testQItem.Status != 'Aborted')
            {   //Remove the job Id if it is not complete yet.
                completedTestJobIds.remove(testJobId);
                break;
            }
        }
    }       
    return completedTestJobIds;
}
```

Comment: Avoid asking question with How, please let us know if you have a specific issue and share what you have tried so far?

Comment: I am struggling to create test data for this method.

Comment: I thought that it need actual class id. But this line let me allow to go further without value. ApexTestQueueItem testQueueItem = new ApexTestQueueItem();